# Html.ValidationSummary shows but I have not Required attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a model.

it looks like this

```
public class AddEditNotificationViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public TimeSpan TimeOfDayToRun { get; set; }

        public string[] DaysRunning { get; set; }

        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string CampaignId { get; set; }

        public int ForHowManyWeeks { get; set; }

        public DateTimeOffset StartDate { get; set; }

        public bool RunForever { get; set; }

        public string TimeZone { get; set; }
    }
```

I have this `@Html.ValidationSummary( false )` in my view.

It shows erros for 3 properties, but I have no Required attribute on them.

Seems spooky ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value types (like `bool` and `int`) are considered as Required by default, unless you use a `Nullable<T>` type.

In your model, `TimeOfDayToRun`, `ForHowManyWeeks` and `RunForever` are non-nullable value types. If you replace the type of `TimeOfDayToRun` with `Nullable<TimeSpan>` or `TimeSpan?`, you're telling MVC binder to allow null values, and there won't be any validation errors.

Try the following model:

```
public class AddEditNotificationViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public TimeSpan? TimeOfDayToRun { get; set; }

    public string[] DaysRunning { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string CampaignId { get; set; }

    public int? ForHowManyWeeks { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset StartDate { get; set; }

    public bool? RunForever { get; set; }

    public string TimeZone { get; set; }
}
```